# Proof that " If $\mu$ is continuous from below at every set $E \in $ a ring, then $\mu$ is $\sigma$-additive."

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-explanation

[image]
**Proof**:
[image]

I don't understand two things about this proof:

1. How does the set $E = \cup_{i=1}^{\infty}E_{i}$ exist in $\mathcal{R}$? as a ring $\mathcal{R}$ is closed under finite union.
2. $\{F_{n}\} = \cup_{i=1}^{n} E_{i} \in \mathcal{R}$  is a monotone increasing sequence, as the limit of $\{F_{n}\} = \cup_{i=1}^{n} E_{i}$, how does this limit of $\{F_{n}\} = \cup_{i=1}^{\infty}E_{i} $ ?

I think I might have misunderstood something, and hope someone can help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1. I think it is closed under countable union via a sigma ring.

2.I think this is monotone convergence theorem.

Comment: According the definition in Halmos's book countable additivity on a ring is defined as follows: $E_i$'s belong to the ring, $E_i$'s disjoint and $\cup_i E_i$ is also in the ring implies $\mu (\cup_i E_i)=\sum \mu(E_i)$.  You cannot prove that the union is in the ring; it is an assumption. For 2) just show that each side is contained in the other.

Comment: @Hawk Thanks for the reply, OK, well. The theorem is stated "$\mathcal{R}$ is a ring".. well a "$\sigma$-ring is a ring, but a ring it not a $sigma$-ring.. I am reading the section of set functions now,  about to start outer measure, the monotone convergence theorem will come later.

Comment: @Hawk You just cannot prove that $\cup_{i=1}^{\infty} E_i$ belongs to the ring if $\{E_i\}$ is a disjoint sequence in it. There are obvious counter-examples.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thanks for the reply,  I just don't think this assumption is good enough to prove the theorem. I have had a look at the Halmos's book, the explanation is very clear. Basically, continuity from below implies $\mu$ is $\sigma$-additive, by the definition of continuity from below. thanks again!